# How to set tooltip dynamically for textblock in dataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip

Each entry in my listbox has the template below. How do I programmatically set the tooltip for Price and for ProductName? What ids can I use? **Please note that I want to distinguish the 2 items: Price and ProductName and display a different tooltip for each even though they belong to the same entry in listbox.**

As you see, setting the tooltip in xaml (as seen for Price below) is straightforward. But I need the flexibility of setting it dynamically. Thanks.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DockPanel >
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text = "{Binding ProductName}" />
        <TextBlock Text="   " />
        <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Price}" ToolTip="Price" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Just a side-note:  consider replacing your TextBlock of blanks, presumably used as a separator, with a Rectangle of width 'n'.

Comment: @GayotFow, can you explain (or provide a link) why using a Rectangle is a better approach please?

Comment: @Ben, it's more light weight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the tooltip (you can bind almost any property) so that when you assign to the property the UI will update. Your best bet would be to make a property somewhere (like the object that has your Price property) and bind to that critter. Just make sure that you use a `DependencyProperty` or use `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DockPanel>
       <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text = "{Binding ProductName}" />
       <TextBlock Text="   " />
       <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Price}" ToolTip="{Binding PriceTooltipProperty}" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a converter, converters take in a type of object, then you could check what that is? i.e. a string or a number and return a string with whatever tooltip you wanted.

```
{Binding Path=Price, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToTooltipConverter}}
```

Then your converter could look something like this.

```
public class ObjectToTooltipConverter: IValueConverter {

 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  if(value is Decimal)
  {
    return "The value was a decimal";
  }
  if(value is String)
  {
    return "The value was a string";
```

}